# 100-sided dice was rolled 98 times, how do you choose next numbes to bet, based on current outcomes.

Tags: probability, dice

100-sided dice was rolled 98 times, 
Numbers form 1 to 50 were rolled exactly once, except number 25, which wasn't rolled yet.
Number 75 was rolled 49 times
You can only bet if the next roll result will be below 51 or above 49.

How do you choose ?, how to calculate which bet is better ?
ELI5 please

And would it be more reasonable to chose below 51, if 75 was rolled only 48 times ?

EDIT: yes dice is fair
EDIT sorry, below 51 or above 49.

Comment: I imagine this will depend on whether you believe the dice is biased or not

Comment: You can't, you aren't even telling us if the die is fair.

Comment: Yes, dice is fair, probability of rolling any number is 1/100 every single time, i didn't know the word for that.

Comment: If the dice is fair and the outcomes independent, basically you know absolutely nothing about the next roll.

Comment: (What is ELI5 by the way?)

Comment: "Explain Like I'm Five."

Comment: explain like I am five

Comment: Actually, since a 100-sided die cannot be a regular polyhedron, I tend to doubt its fairness (though not as much as the results so far might suggest)

Comment: lets suppose it is fair

Comment: and what would happen if number 75 was rolled less then 49 times ? would it be better to choose above 49 side ?

Comment: @Asmodat We can assume that the result of a roll does not depend on the result of a roll we have got before: $P(X_n|X_{n-1})=P(X_n)$. Therefore you still chose "above 49".

Comment: @Hagen: Why does it need to be regular? [$10$-sided dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_trapezohedron) aren't regular, but no one doubts their fairness.

Answer (score 3):

If the die is fair, then the probability the roll will be above $51$ is $49/100$ and the probability the roll is below $49$ will be $48/100$. The previous rolls do not change the fact that the die is fair. So technically, since it's slightly more likely, you should bet that the roll is above $51$.

If you do not assume the die is fair, and you know nothing about the die beforehand, then the maximum likelihood estimate for what you should choose would be whichever is greater, the number of rolls less than $49$ or the number of rolls greater than $51$. If you have prior knowledge about how the die might behave, then you can use Bayes rule (you can look it up online) to figure out what to do but the calculations get messier.

UPDATE: The question has been changed to "below 51" or "above 49". If the die is fair, then "below 51" has chances $50/100$, and the chances of "above 49" are $51/100$, so you should choose "above 49" if the die is known to be fair. All the other reasoning stands as is (for a possibly unfair die), just substituting in the new different things you bet on.

Comment: sorry, I mean below 51 or above 49, I think distribution of the numbers in the infinite amount of time should be equal to 1/100, so there must be some way to choose the side to bet on

Comment: @Asmodat Updated answer to reflect this

Answer (score -3):

Bet on 75. Fair dice can't fall on one outcome in 49 rolls out of 98. The probability is $ 10^{-96}$. It is greater than the number of atoms in the universe.

PS. If this is study task than bets are equal. Next outcome has absolutely no dependance from previous ones.

Comment: They can. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: but distribution of all numbers in the infinite amount a time should be equal for all numbers

Comment: Yes you are right. This was a joke answer. The right answer is bets are equal with probabilities 0.5 each. Next outcomes has absolutely no dependance from previous ones.

Comment: and what would happen if number 75 was rolled less then 49 times ? would it be better to choose above 49 side ?

Comment: This is a poor answer. I downvoted it.

Comment: If your assumption of dice fairness is right than previous rolls results has absolutely no importance.

Comment: I know previous rolls have no importance, but if by half of infinite time only lets say below 51 side was thrown, and not a single number from above 49, then you are almost 100% sure next time will be different imo. I know half the infinite is infinite, but lets suppose there is something like this, because there are smaller and greater infinities.